# Use of material design components in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to intergrate material design components in my application? I find them very nice and would like to add them to my application.

Comment: Which components specifically. E.g. `TextComponent` and `TextLayout` use material design principles. So does `FloatingActionButton` etc. Try to describe the specific UI you want and we can point you to the way of achieving it

Comment: I want to do the component Menus.

Comment: You mean the side menu?
That's pretty easy to style in the material design styling. What have you tried so far? Do you use CSS or designer tool?